# Should we merge and synonymise [history] and [history-of]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Looking at the [history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and [history-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tags, it is hard to tell which questions fall into the [history-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tag, without also falling into the [history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag. What questions would fall into [history-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), but not [history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)? If there are none, should we merge the two tags and synonymise them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag was only used on one question, which I've now retagged [history-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), thus essentially accomplishing a merge. There's no point in synonymising these two tags, since typing `history` into the tag box will autocomplete to [history-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) anyway.

### **How about [history-of-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-literature) instead?**

This tag will show up in autocomplete for either `history` or `history-of`, and it has a clearer name to avoid confusion with [historical-context](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context). We need to be careful with "history", since it could refer either to history of literature (themes, ideas, etc.) or to history of the real world outside of literature as it relates to literary works. Using [history-of-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-literature) and [historical-context](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context) separately would solve this issue.

---

**EDIT:** I've now edited all the [history-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) questions to [history-of-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-literature) and made a new tag wiki.

Comment: But, doesn't [tag:history] make more sense than [tag:history-of]?

Comment: History sound and looks better then history-of

Comment: @Benjamin I agree [tag:history-of] sounds a bit odd. How about [tag:history-of-literature] instead? Calling the tag just `history` would lead to confusion with the [tag:historical-context] tag, and typing `history-of` wouldn't autocomplete to that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That makes some sense. Could I post it in a separate answer?

Comment: @Randal'Thor We use [history-of-gaming] on [rpg.se] to positive results. It's been quite unambiguous for us.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I really don't mind that

Comment: @Benjamin Edited my answer.

Comment: How long should we wait for consensus?

Comment: @doppelgreener Excellent, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Benjamin The easiest way to achieve this would be by a mod-merge of [tag:history-of] into [tag:history-of-literature]. We could also retag by hand, since it's only five questions, but let's give it a couple of days first in case someone comes up with something else.

Comment: @Benjamin either couple of days or humongous vote response.

Comment: history of literature makes it sounds you asking about the history of *all of* literature, rather than the "history" of certain work, trope, concept, etc. I think it should remain "history of"

Comment: @Skooba The history of a certain work, trope, concept, etc. is part of the history of literature.